# How to run all tasks in array and process the results continuously (async, await)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have following code:

```
        List<Task<int>> taskArray = new List<Task<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            taskArray.Add(myCrawler.getWebPageCharsCount("https://www.something.com"));
        }
```

The method looks like this:

```
    public Task<int> getWebPageCharCount(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Task<string> task = client.GetStringAsync(url);
            string taskResult = await task;
            return taskResult.Length;
        });
    }
```

After this, there is a 100 threads running, what I want to achive is to process the result in main thread after each individual task is done, not to wait to all results, which would I do with the following code:

```
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);

        foreach (var res in results)
        {
            myTextBox.Text += res.ToString() + "\n";
        }
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
        foreach (var task in taskArray)
        {
            var result = await task;
            myTextBox.Text += result.ToString() + "\n";
        }
```

But after testing and reading about await in loops, I know it's running synchronized. Is there a way to process the results continuously in main thread?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx). It may help you.

Comment: See [Processing tasks as they complete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions to this, but the simplest is to use `await Task.WhenAny()`, which returns a completed `Task`, which you then process and remove from the list of tasks, then repeat the same until the list is empty.

**Example as requested**:

```
List<Task<int>> indexingArray = new List<Task<int>>(taskArray);
var results = new int[taskArray.Count];

while (taskArray.Any())
{
    Task<int> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskArray).ConfigureAwait(false);
    results[indexingArray.IndexOf(completedTask)] = completedTask.Result;
    taskArray.Remove(completedTask);
}

myTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", results);
```

(I added an indexing collection to get the correct index for the results.  There are probably better ways to do that but as the question is about tasks I'll leave it as-is).

Comment: Could you please provide me an example?
I came up with "recursive" solution (not exactly recursive, because every call should be, after await, when is another call 
proceed, finished - but when is the asynchronous operation done already, I mean during the new call, it will be processed right away) but it seems to be little more greedy regards to the resources compare to the solution with WhenAll().

Comment: It is an O(N^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

> what I want to achive is to process the result in main thread after each individual task is done, not to wait to all results

The *simplest* solution is to introduce an `async` method that corresponds to that "process" concept. You already have an `async` way of "retrieval", you just need to introduce an `async` operation of "retrieve and process":

```
// (getWebPageCharCount is unchanged)

private Task GetAndDisplayWebPageCharCount(string url)
{
  var res = await myCrawler.getWebPageCharCount(url);
  myTextBox.Text += res.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

Used as such:

```
List<Task> taskArray = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  taskArray.Add(GetAndDisplayWebPageCharCount("https://www.something.com"));
await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
```

On a side note, there's abosolutely no need for `Task.Run` wrapping `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`. Also, the "100 threads running" remark is incorrect; there are 100 *tasks in progress*.

Comment: A minor point, perhaps: that won't output the results in the original order, though, which seems from his original code to be a requirement?

Comment: @sellotape: I believe that's not what the OP wants: `want to achive is to process the result in main thread after each individual task is done`.